# import a txt file in python and print all lines with specific word in string

Tags: python, python-2.7, utc

I receive data that looks like the below:

```
0,JW111101,Run Name
0,111116,Date
0,+2.5,Increment
0,2=0,Start Station
0,1=Fri 11 Nov 2016 14:21:44,Date & Time Stamp
0,6=1 Off 4On,Cycle Times
0,6=Fluke 189B,Meter Type
0,6=Racal Landstar,GPS Reciever
0,1=Fri 11 Nov 2016 14:21:47,Date & Time Stamp
0,6=COMPANY NAME,142156.00,29.0638153,95.3436157,-1.2
0,6=LINE NAME,142156.00,29.0638153,95.3436157,-1.2
1,6=Test Station,142255.00,29.0638145,95.3436133,-0.9
1,6=-1559 On NG,142255.00,29.0638145,95.3436133,-0.9
1,6=-1169 Off NG,142255.00,29.0638145,95.3436133,-0.9
1,6=1Approx.,142255.00,29.0638145,95.3436133,-0.9
1,6=AC 0.735,142255.00,29.0638145,95.3436133,-0.9
1,1558,GPS Not Available
1,1460,142350.00,29.0638166,95.3436115,-0.9
1,1185z,142351.00,29.0638167,95.3436116,-0.9
1,1554,142352.00,29.0638166,95.3436116,-0.9
```

I would like to find the smallest and biggest numbers in the 3rd column.   The third column is actually a utc timestamp.
My eventual goal is to be able to figure out when they start, when they end, and their duration.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: yea. look for string operations, the `datetime` module (strptime, strftime, toordinal) and the `max` function.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data is in a file called `random.csv` here's how you can read the data in.

```
import csv

list_of_stuff = []
with open('random.csv') as readcsv:
    row_object = csv.reader(readcsv)
    for value in row_object:
        list_of_stuff.append(value)

print list_of_stuff
```

Now you have a list of lists where each sublist is a line of your file. Here's the documentation on reading in csv files: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Your third column includes strings and integers that can't be converted to timestamps so I can't help you with that. Let's assume the third column was all integers, though. Then you could use this in addition to my code above:

```
third_column = [row[2] for row in list_of_stuff]
print "max: ", max(third_column)
print "min: ", min(third_column)
print "range: ", max(third_column) - min(third_column)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great to start with. The data actually comes to me in a .txt file, but we usually convert it to csv anyway.